# How to set margin in an article having figures and tables

Tags: margins

I am writing a journal article which contains some figures and tables. The left and right margins are not same. I have used the following command:

```
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}
```

I have tried setting different values but nothing is changing the margins. How to fix this problem?

Comment: the code you show sets the left and right margins to 2cm, if you are not seeing that it is due to code you have not shown, so we can not help. If the article is for a journal you should almost certainly not change the margin or page layout, that is a choice of the journal publisher, not individual authors

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the code as shown below

```
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=2cm,
 right=2cm,
 }
```

Source: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Page_size_and_margins

Check out this link, it has good documentation on customizing the margins.

Comment: In the question we have `left=2cm` and `right=2cm` not `top=2cm`. So I doubt that using `top=2cm` instead of `right=2cm` would help to have the same margin width at the left an right.

Comment: My bad, 'top' was a typo, I meant 'right'. I have edited it to reflect that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: But moving the options from `\usepackage` to an explicit `\geometry` does not change anything. So how should this answer the question?